# How do you convert datset with multiple tables into generic list

Tags: c#, asp.net, collections, linq-to-dataset

Below logic will works fine if i have single datatable in dataset but how can we modify the below logic to make it work if i have two tables in dataset.

```
var empList = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(dataRow => new Employee{Name =     dataRow.Field<string>("Name")}.ToList();
```

lets say i have Employee class and one nested object in it..

```
Public class Employee
{
public string name;
public string ID;
public Jobdetails job;
}

Public class Jobdetails
{
public string role;
public string salary;
}
```

i have to check whether there are two tables in dataset or not.if there are two tables exist i have to load first table(it will have employee name and id) into Employee class and second table(it will have role and salary columns) to job object in employee class.

if there is only one table i have to load first table to employee object and keeping jobdetails object as null since there is no second table.

please Advise what is the best approach to achieve above scenario?

Comment: you can check table count in dataset as : ds.Table.Count & for second table you can covert to list same as employee just change Tables[0] to Tables[1] if table count is 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static DataTable ConvertToDatatable<T>(this IList<T> data)
        {
            PropertyDescriptorCollection props =
                TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            for (int i = 0; i < props.Count; i++)
            {
                PropertyDescriptor prop = props[i];
                table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType);
            }
            object[] values = new object[props.Count];
            foreach (T item in data)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                {
                    values[i] = props[i].GetValue(item);
                }
                table.Rows.Add(values);
            }
            return table;
        }






DataTable dtList = ConvertToDatatable(request.Members);
```